React Native Expo Google Maps Shows Blank White Screen
I am working on a React-Native app using Expo, and I am trying to integrate Google Maps on the home screen. However, the map does not load and only shows a blank white screen. Here's the relevant code and configuration:
    import React from 'react';
    import { StyleSheet } from 'react-native';
    import MapView, { Marker, PROVIDER_GOOGLE } from 'react-native-maps';
    
    export default function HomeScreen() {
      return (
        <MapView
          provider={PROVIDER_GOOGLE}
          style={StyleSheet.absoluteFill}
          initialRegion={{
            latitude: 41.0082,
            longitude: 28.9784,
            latitudeDelta: 0.0922,
            longitudeDelta: 0.0421,
          }}
        >
          <Marker coordinate={{ latitude: 41.0082, longitude: 28.9784 }} />
        </MapView>
      );
    }

app.json configuration
    "ios": {
      "googleServicesFile": "./GoogleService-Info.plist",
      "supportsTablet": true,
      "bundleIdentifier": "com.xxx.xxx.xxx",
      "config": {
        "googleMapsApiKey": "XXX"
      }
    },

Steps I have taken

I added the googleMapsApiKey under the ios.config section in app.json.
I ensured the PROVIDER_GOOGLE is used in the MapView.
The app has permissions for location access.
I verified the API Key is enabled for Google Maps SDK for iOS in the Google Cloud Console.

Despite these steps, the map screen remains blank.
What I have tried

Confirmed that the googleMapsApiKey is valid and has no restrictions.
Checked that the Google Maps SDK for iOS is enabled in the Google Cloud Console.
Cleaned the Expo cache with expo start -c.
Rebuilt the app and tested on a physical device as well as on the iOS simulator.

Questions

Am I missing any configuration for Google Maps with Expo on iOS?
Do I need to include any additional native dependencies or steps since I'm using Expo?
Could there be an issue with how Expo handles the googleMapsApiKey or permissions?




I was facing the same issue when i updated my expo from 50 to 52 and on my side the bug got resolved when I changed the provider from PROVIDER_GOOGLE to PROVIDER_DEFAULT.
Solution
So just import PROVIDER_DEFAULT and use PROVIDER_DEFAULT instead of PROVIDER_GOOGLE.
   <MapView provider={PROVIDER_DEFAULT}>
      ...
   </MapView>

Version
    "expo": "^52.0.18",
    "react-native": "0.76.5",
    "react-native-maps": "1.18.0",



But, default is Apple Maps @Kashif

@Bertug, yes now the default map will work according to their documentation. we can't use google maps in ios devices in expo go.

But, it is not expo go

then it is what?

Just Expo......
